# Can't use vuetify variables in nuxt.js project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

Trying to create a new component style using the `$display-breakpoints` stylus variabled from Vuetify (as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56230843/867891)) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<style lang="stylus">
.submit-container
  @media $display-breakpoints.sm-and-up
    font-size 5em
</style>
```

I get the following error:

```
$display-breakpoints has no property .sm-and-up
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to import the variables stylus file:

```
<style lang="stylus">
@import '../../assets/style/variables.styl'
.submit-container
  @media $display-breakpoints.sm-and-up
    color #ef4655;
</style>
```